# How to keep position which scrolled to when navigate back to previous page with angular 11?

Tags: angular

I am using angular 11 for web SPA and I am facing an issue with navigation back to previous page. How can I keep the position of previous page which scroll to or that action is default browser's behavior?

Thank you very much for your consideration!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly if you want to get back to previous page programatically.

If that is what you want, you can do that with "location":

```
import { Location } from '@angular/common';
....
constructor(
...
    private _location: Location,
...
  ) {
...
  }

  backToPreviousPage() {
    this._location.back();
  }
```

Comment: Thanks Juan, but I mean how we can keep the position of previous page after back?

Ex: I am on page A and I scroll down to (x, y) coordinate, after that I go to page B and after I back to page A then how we can keep that position?

Comment: I was afraid that you wanted that. I'm sorry but I don't know how to do it (I don't even know if that is possible, because when you navigate to new components, I guess the old ones are deleted from memory.. so we would need something that 'authomatic' save the position in the scroll, etc... I don't know..). Anyway, is something useful that I would have needed sometimes as well... I keep here to see other answers!

Answer (score 0):

i would suggest using a service to manage your state and position. depending on how much navigation history you want to keep would make this more or less complicated.

a simple service would look something like this.

```js
import { Location } from '@angular/common';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class NavService {
  private _lastScrollPositionY: number;
  private _lastScrollPositionX: number;

  constructor(
    private _location: Location,
    private _router: Router,
  ) { }

  back() {
    this._location.back();
    if (this._lastScrollPositionY || this._lastScrollPositionX) {
      window.scroll(this._lastScrollPositionX, this._lastScrollPositionY);
      this._lastScrollPositionY = this._lastScrollPositionX = null;
    }
  }

  navigate(route: string[]) {
    this._lastScrollPositionX = window.scrollX;
    this._lastScrollPositionY = window.scrollY;
    this._router.navigate(route)
  }

}
``
```

Comment: thanks, but you can you use this one https://angular.io/api/common/ViewportScroller instead

Answer (score 0):

I tried this solution and its work like a charm

```
this.router.events.pipe(filter(e => e instanceof Scroll)).subscribe((e: any) => {
  setTimeout(() => { 
    if (e.position) {
      this.viewportScroller.scrollToPosition(e.position);
    } else if (e.anchor) { 
      this.viewportScroller.scrollToAnchor(e.anchor);
    } else { 
      this.viewportScroller.scrollToPosition([0, 0]);
    }
  }, 300);
});
```

if your app still blinks after back, we can implement caching data mechanism to resolve it.